# Visual Studio not recognizing Form.Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project I've been working on for a long time, and randomly today one of the designer.cs files is behaving strangely.

The following screen shot shows how the icon in Solution explorer does not appear as it should do.

[image]

When I open the corrupted frmCase.Designer.cs file all my code is there, but I notice that intellisense is not recognizing objects

[image]

Contrast with another Designer.cs file where intellisense colour codes the objects.

[image]

I have no idea what this has occurred, or how to rectify it.  Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: You forgot the screenshot

Comment: Is the `partial` keyword from the class definition header still there?

Comment: Yes the Namespace and partial class definition are still there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on "fmCase.Desinger.cs" select "Include in project" should help you

Comment: Oh thank you so much - so relieved it was an easy fix - but still at a loss as to how this happened in the first place.

Comment: I don't know, how does it happened, but links on all included files stored in 'csproj' file it can be corrupted in some way. Who knows.